# Rewiring my own Vect but encountering issues

Tags: idris

I was trying to re-implement the Vect data type to become more familiar with the dependent types. This is what I wrote:

```
data Vect : (len : Nat) -> (elem : Type) -> Type where
  Nil : Vect Z elem
  (::) : (x : elem) -> (xs : Vect len elem) -> Vect (S len) elem

append : Vect n elem -> Vect m elem -> Vect (n + m) elem
append [] y = y
append (x :: xs) y = x :: append xs y
```

I can define, for example `Vect 4 Nat` and others as well. But if I try `append (Vect 4 Nat) (Vect 3 Nat)` I get an error that I am not able to parse:

```
When checking an application of function Main.append:
        Type mismatch between
                Type (Type of Vect len elem)
        and
                Vect n elem (Expected type)
```

Clearly there is something wrong in the way I think about this.

Any suggestion?

Also when I try to create `Vect 4 [1,2,3,4]` I get an error:

```
When checking argument elem to type constructor Main.Vect:
        Can't disambiguate since no name has a suitable type: 
                Prelude.List.::, Main.::, Prelude.Stream.::
```

So I guess I am quite lost ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of `Vect` and `append` look fine to me, but it's how you're creating values that's the problem. You're mixing up the type constructor `Vect` with the data constructors `Nil` and `::`. You should create values of type `Vect len elem` with calls to `Nil` and `::`.

In particular, `Vect 4 Nat` is a type, but `append` expects a value of that type, like `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil` (or `[1,2,3,4]` which is just syntactic sugar for the former).

And `Vect 4 [1,2,3,4]` isn't possible since `[1,2,3,4]` is a value not a `Type`

Comment: I see, thanks! Now if I type `1::2::3::4::Nil` in REPL idris interprets that as a List type. How can I get it to interpret it as a `Vect 4 Nat` type?

Comment: @geguze `the (Vect _ _) (1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil)` might do it, but if you use the value where it expects your `Vect` type (e.g. in a call to `append`), it should infer that type automatically